# icon for QT app

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I'm using QTCreator to build an application on Mac. At this time the application icon is the default one set by Qt Creator.

I would like to set one custom specific to my app.

What I have in in the .qrc file, I have added

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>images/logo.icns</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I have made a try on my main.cpp by adding

```
QIcon icon(":images/logo.icns");
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setWindowIcon(icon);
```

it doesn't work... I have tried to do it in another class in which I define how the window of the app is done

```
QIcon icon(":images/logo.icns");

QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("PULS"));
window->resize(600, 600);
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
centralWidget->setWindowIcon(icon);
```

It's also not working.

Comment: are you trying to set the .exe icon (the one you see in explorer), or the icon in the application window title?

Comment: Also, if you are using the resource system, your path should look like ":/images/logo.icns" (note the slash after the `:`)

Answer (score 0):

The icon's path may be incorrect.

try to change

```
QIcon icon(":images/logo.icns");
```

to

```
QIcon icon(":/images/logo.icns");
```

cause of your `.qrc` file define the `prefix`:

```
<qresource prefix="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the icon for the executable file you need:

```
ICON = logo.icns
```

In your .pro file.

To set the window icon you need to call

```
QIcon icon(":/images/logo.icns");
centralWidget->setWindowIcon(icon);
```

Or try using a .png

Comment: I am developing in Mac, but it is going to be lunched in both Windows and Mac systems. What should I do ?